# What do I do about a user who makes seemingly trivial edits to my question?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, behavior, trivial

I asked a [valid question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60522723/angular-faulty-auto-import-with-path-alias) about an issue I have in an Angular project and provided a detailed info about settings of my project. Just about an hour after I asked the question, some user started suggesting edits repeatedly even after I (and other users in the review queue) rejected their pointless edits.

They're either adding three dots at the end of the codeblock, adds one space after the last word, changes the title to grammatically incorrect version or even changes tags to something completely different (changed [package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package.json) to [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) which is a tag for something else).

Is there something I can do about it? I think they're now offended that I rejected all of their useless edits and downvoted my question.

Comment: Some of their edits are superfluous at best, but others aren't. Bugs me more that they put non-English reasons in the comments. [Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12548071/brandon?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

Comment: You don't need angular in your title, that's what tags are for

Comment: You can't know if he downvoted either. Votes are confidential.

Comment: Okay...I'm still trying to clean this question up at least a little; I think we're done with the pile-on for this one.  There's something constructive to be discussed here; we should seek to discuss that from now.

Comment: No matter how the meta question here is written, suggesting 7 edits on the same question is not ok. Especially not when wrong tags are added, example content is modified. The same goes for non-english edit descriptions which, in addition, are wrong. None of the edits is about formatting.

Comment: I'm surprised that repeated rejected edits of the same user on the same post don't trigger an auto mod flag. And when I see what kind of their edits got approved, then I'm disappointed by those reviewers again.

Comment: I agree that this user does make superfluous edits; I rejected one of their earlier edits because they missed a lot of obvious things that needed changing. I remember because they used exactly the same Portuguese edit summary. I'd flag the question for moderator attention and write a detailed message about the edits.

Comment: @Tom IIRC 2 rollbacks from the same user on a single post does

Comment: My guess, looking at that user's activity, is that they're doing serial tiny edits to get a few extra rep points and shiny editor badges.

Comment: @BenjaminW. In fact, it looks to me like they're doing the same with [a sock puppet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13013157/tretada?tab=activity&sort=revisions) too

Comment: If you think that any user is abusing the system in some way, and this clearly is such case, you can always use custom flag (in need of moderator intervention) on the post (even if it is yours) and explain the situation.

Comment: I already raised a flag but with no effect.

Comment: @dallows The mods' flag view doesn't necessarily give a lot of context. Hopefully the custom flag about the sock puppetry on that other post had enough information in it to be actionable.

Comment: They're also farming rep (edits and answers) from [this other new account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12994027/prodigy268-pt) (and possible sockpuppet).

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. Sorry the issue was missed the first time. I, too, missed it when I first read your question, and thought the same as the moderator who declined your flag. After looking further into it, moderators have confirmed that @Blastfurnace's suspicions were correct: there was definitely some sockpuppetry going on. This is being cleaned up now.

Comment: @CodyGray: is the sockpuppet show the only reason for you to step in? It is not mentioned in, nor an important part of, dallows' question. It's like a policeman stopping a car for having a broken head light when there still is a bleeding pedestrian hanging over the bonnet.

Comment: @CodyGray The repeated edit suggestions and many of the individual edits were inappropriate even disregarding the sockpuppetry. Can you address why the flag was declined?